# Could I use Intel C++ Compiler without Installing Visual Studio [on Windows]

Tags: c++, intel

I need intel compiler for my work on My windows [Win7 Prof, 64bit]. I am planning to download the trial version for the same i.e. Intel® Parallel Studio XE. 
Could I install this without installing Visual Studio ? I wish to use this on command line only i.e. icl.exe through Cygwin.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

[Per the documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581609), you have support for:

- Command Line (What you're looking for)
- Visual Studio
- Eclipse
- XCode

Comment: I checked in the document but it says "Click Intel 64 Visual Studio mode". To invoke the compiler from the command line:
•Windows 8
1.From the Start screen, swipe up from the bottom edge, or right-click the screen and click All apps at the bottom-left corner of the screen.
2.In the Apps screen, scroll to the right until you see the program group for your Intel product.
3.Click Intel 64 Visual Studio mode or IA-32 Visual Studio mode to open a command window.

Comment: @Anil - Did you have a question about these steps?

Comment: Yes, I thought If we do not need Visual Studio then why will the "Intel 64 Visual Studio mode" is required to be clicked. Does it mean that visual studio is already installed on the machine ?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581612 - It would help if you followed the right instructions =P

Comment: I am getting following error:                                                                          I tried below command in Cygwin :                                                              icl.exe helloWorld.cc                                                                            Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on IA-32, Version 16.0 Build 20160415
Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 14-jul-2016 UTC.
icl: error #10114: Microsoft Visual C++ not found in path

Comment: I am getting following error:                                                                          I tried below command in Cygwin :                                                              icl.exe helloWorld.cc                                                              Error: Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on IA-32, Version 16.0 Build 20160415
Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

icl: NOTE: The evaluation period for this product ends on 14-jul-2016 UTC.
icl: error #10114: Microsoft Visual C++ not found in path